# Sidemenu In codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I just try to bulid control panel using MVC (codeigniter), I just need way to how make a side menu in home page and when I click in the link in menu the page open in the right side, and the menu stay in the left side.

I need coorect way to do this using MVC.

Comment: You have to try something and offer here part of code that doesn't work. Check here [how to ask](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: Please show us some code in your question by clicking on edit button below tags.

Answer (score 1):

I use this simple way to make Views to make exactly what your asking.

```
<?php
//This is mainpage.php
$data['page_id'] = $_GET['page_id'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <!-- HERE Comes Side Bar -->
        <?php $this->load->view('sidebar'); ?>
    </div>
    <div>
        <!-- HERE Comes Main Content -->
        <?php $this->load->view('maincontent',$data) ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Mainpage.php** is a master page who holds code for both, side menu as well as the content page

This code if for side bar **sidebar.php** in view folder

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="somelink/?page_id=dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="somelink/?page_id=settings">Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="somelink/?page_id=logout">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**sidebar.php** page only holds different links, but all links have GET variable named "page_id" which decides which page is to be displayed in the content page.

Now, in mainpage.php you can notice that maincontent.php is loaded as view with passing $data which has page_id as variable, which is drived from sidebar. this will help to display the content in content side.

This code is for **maincontent.php** in view folder

```
<?php
if(file_exists(APPPATH.'views/'.$page_id.'.php')){
    $this->load->view($page_id);
}else{
    show_404();
}
```

this has always worked for me in non ajax page displays...so will work for you to.
Thanks...

Comment: actually this is the best way, because anyone can understand the flow, so anyone can edit it...